# Howto SHA0 in ruby (>=1.9.3)

Tags: ruby, digest

How to get hex of string in SHA-0 in ruby >=1.9.3?

I searched on GitHub and here, I looked at the module `Digest`, but couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lot of crypto methods in the OpenSSL module, including SHA.
(SHA was later named SHA0)

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Digest.html

```
require 'openssl'
digest_maker = OpenSSL::Digest::SHA.new
digest = digest_maker.digest( 'your_message_here' )
```

You can convert the digest to hex with unpack:

```
hex_digest = digest.unpack('H*')
hex_digest[0]   # because array is returned by unpack
```

Comment: Thanks, OpenSSL is great!